# Cannot see my server in the browser

Tags: docker, networking

I'm using Docker Toolbox on Windows 10.

I'm starting a server using `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

I'm getting the response `Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/`

However when I'm going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in my browser, it's not working.

Any idea? What should I check?

I've tried docker `run -p 8000:8000 my_image` but I get `Bind for 0.0.0.0:8000 failed: port is already allocated.`

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: on-failure
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: on-failure
  elasticsearch:
    image: "elasticsearch:2.4-alpine"
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
  politikon:
    image: *****
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "2233:22"
      - "8000:8000"
    dns:
      - 8.8.8.8
      - 8.8.4.4
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT=5432"
      - "POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR=postgres"
      - "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=*****.settings.dev"
      - "BONSAI_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200/"
      - "ELASTIC_USERNAME=*****"
      - "ELASTIC_PASSWORD=*****"
    volumes:
      - $PWD:/app
    restart: on-failure
```

And here is my Docker file (without some irrelevant lines):

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -y -qq --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -y wget

RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update -y -qq --fix-missing
RUN apt-get upgrade -y -qq
RUN apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip postgresql-client-common postgresql postgresql-contrib postgresql-9.5 libpq-dev git libmemcached-dev curl openssh-server mercurial gettext vim libjpeg-dev libjpeg8-dev

RUN echo "locale-gen en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/profile
RUN echo "dpkg-reconfigure locales" >> /etc/profile    
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile    
RUN echo "KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config    
RUN echo "PermitUserEnvironment=yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config

ENV PORT 8000
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 22

RUN touch /root/.bash_profile
RUN echo "cd /app" >> /root/.bash_profile

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN touch /root/.ssh/environment

CMD env >> /root/.ssh/environment; export -p | grep _ >> /etc/profile; /usr/sbin/sshd -D;

ADD /requirements.txt /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get install zlib1g-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD tail -f LICENSE
```

Comment: Docker won't expose *anything* to the outside world unless you explicitly configure it to do so. You'll have to configure it to expose the internal port 8000 outside of the container

Comment: When you run a container you specify the ports to expose with `-p`, eg `docker run -p 8000:8000`. How did you start the container?

Comment: I've tried `docker run -p 8000:8000 my_image` but I get `Bind for 0.0.0.0:8000 failed: port is already allocated.`

Comment: I normally start it with `docker build -t my_name .` and `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: The port 8000 is already allocated. Have you stopped the local server?

Comment: Can you provide your Dockerfile and your docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: I added them to the main question.

Comment: It's not a docker related problem, everything seems ok. You have to find which process use the port 8000 and kill it, then it should work.

Comment: I checked with `netstat -aon` and there isn't any process using port 8000